# Reformatted quotes in swagger

Tags: json, swagger

I'm working on an web API developed in Visual Studio using C#, and using Swagger to view the code documentation and play with the API.  The code comments contain an input example:

```
/// ## Examples
///   * An array of guids:
///   {"SomeGuids":["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]}
```

And on the API's Swagger page, the example displays as expected.  However, if I copy the string displayed in the Swagger documentation and use it as input for the API, the double-quotes change.  And when I use Newtonsoft to deserialize the string, it throws an exception.

For example, if I copy the input string from the Swagger documentation, insert a GUID for the x's, and send it to the API:

```
{"SomeGuids":[“1234abcd-1234-abcd-1234-1234abcd1234”]}
```

Then, inside my API code, I try to deserialize the input string:

```
MyDataClass myDataClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDataClass>(TheInputString);
```

It throws an Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException with this message:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: “. Path
>   'SomeGuids', line 1, position 14.

I've tried single quotes, escaping the double-quotes, pasting as plain text.

What can I do, so that Newtonsoft isn't confused by the double-quotes after I copy the string from the Swagger documentation?

Comment: Where do you edit the request body - directly in the browser or in some text editor? If in the browser - do you have any "fancy quotes" extensions installed?

Comment: Nothing that I know of, just Docs, Sheets and Slides and another for meetings.  I may just write something to replace the quotes.

Comment: Did you got solution for it. My response is serialise and can't store it as Json in swagger and if added \ to bypass " it gives \ in response